# VBA, How to open new excel instance

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When I have don't have the excel APP open, the following error is thrown :

> ActiveX Component can't create object

### Steps to reproduce issue :

1 Open Outlook, ALT + F11 And Insert the following sub :

```
Sub Test()
  Dim myXL As New Excel.Application
  Set myXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  Set wb = myXL.Workbooks.Open("MyPath\MyXL.xlsx")
End Sub
```

2. **Close ALL your excel files**
3. Run the sub Test from outlook.

The Error will be thrown on :

```
Set myXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: If you want a *new* instance, you don't need `GetObject`. Just use `myXL` directly since you declared it `As New` (which is bad practice in my opinion)

Comment: @Rory `I tried As New` and the issue was still the same

Comment: I think you missed the part about not using `GetObject`.

Comment: @Rory Indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option should be the next way, I think:

```
   Dim objexcel As Object

   On Error Resume Next 'firstly, try catching the existing open session, if any:
    Set objexcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If err.Number <> 0 Then 'if  no any existing session, create a new one:
        err.Clear: Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
   On Error GoTo 0
```

Having a reference to 'Microsoft Excel ... Object library` you can declare

```
Dim objexcel As Excel.Application
```

and benefit of the intellisense suggestions...

It is also possible to find an Excel open session if you know the full name of a specific workbook open in it:

```
   Set objExcel = GetObject(ThisWorkbook.fullName).Application   
   Debug.Print objExcel.hwnd
```

Or even for a new workbook, open by a third party application, in a new session, as "Book1":

```
   Set objExcel = GetObject("Book1").Application
   Debug.Print objExcel.hwnd
```

If the respective application drops new workbooks (and opens them in the same session), naming them as "Book2", "Book3" and so on, a loop building the workbook name bay concatenation of "Book" root with the incremented variable can be used to get it.